# How do you develop a recurrence relation for the function $f(n) = 5n^2 +3$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

On an exam of mine, I was asked to find a  recurrence relation for the function $f(n) = 5n^2 +3$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. I needed to provide a base case and the actual relation itself. I know the base case is for $n = 1$, were $f(1) = 8$, but I have no idea how to derive the relation from here.

The professor's answer key is as follows, but I don't understand where the intuition/motivation comes from for this solution:

$f(1) = 8, f(n) = 5n^2 + 3 = 5(n - 1)^2 + 3 + 5(2n - 1) = f(n - 1) + 10n - 5$

Where do I start? The above steps seem, at least to me, to be arbitrarily and magically plucked from nowhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write a recurrence of the form $f(n)=f(n-1)+\text{ something.}$  You can just substitute in to find out what the something has to be.  You are given that $f(n)=5n^2+3$, so $f(n-1)=5(n-1)^2+3.$  Then $f(n)-f(n-1)=5n^2+3-5(n-1)^2+3=10n-5$ and you have your something.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to work it out is by simple algebraic elimination. Consider two consecutive terms:

$$
\begin{align}
f(n) &= 5n^2+3 \\
f(n-1) &= 5(n-1)^2+3 = 5n^2-10n+8
\end{align}
$$

Now consider $k = n^2$ as an independent variable:

$$
\begin{align}
f(n) &= 5k+3 \\
f(n-1) &= 5k-10n+8
\end{align}
$$

Eliminate $k$ between the two equations, and you get the posted recurrence:

$$f(n) = f(n - 1) + 10n - 5$$

You can take this one step farther. Write two consecutive terms of the latter recurrence:

$$
\begin{align}
f(n) &= f(n - 1) + 10n - 5 \\
f(n-1) &= f(n - 2) + 10(n-1) - 5 = f(n-2) +10 n -15
\end{align}
$$

Now eliminate $n$ between these two equations, and you get a standard linear recurrence for $f(n)\,$:

$$
f(n)-f(n-1)=f(n-1)-f(n-2)+ 10 \;\;\iff\;\; f(n)=2 f(n-1)-f(n-2)+10
$$

Comment: I think the second order standard recurrence is to be preferred over the professor's answer which is of a "mixed" type, including $n$ both implicitly and explicitly. "Mixed" types require you to separately keep track of $n$ and $f(n)$ when generating the sequence. I also suspect that they are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

The motivation behind rewriting $f(n)$ this way, is to acquire an equation of the form $$f(n)=g(f(n-1)),$$
i.e. we have to rewrite $f(n)$, so that we get some function of $f(n-1)$.
Here, this function is
$$g(x)=x+10n-5.$$

Now you can directly deduct the recurrence relation, by plugging $g$ into $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$.
Here, we get the result
$$x_1=8,~~x_{n+1}=x_n+10n-5$$